# How can I resize the image from (200*200) to (368*368)?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Let's assume that I use YoloV3 to detect a human in an image, and I have the bounding box coordinates. Just like the example here:

[image]

We can use cv2 to extract the pixels of the bounding box, and the image can be like (200*200). I want to feed this to a model that gets image size (368*368).

The question is:

How can I resize the image from (200 by 200) to (368 by 368)?

What are the possible ways that I can use it to do that?

Thanks,

Comment: [cv2.resize](https://www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-resize-image/) is your friend

Answer (score 0):

You can use the openCV library to upscale images with interpolation, for example:

```
import cv2

new_image = cv2.resize(image, (368,368), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
```

The interpolation methods available are:

- INTER_NEAREST
- INTER_LINEAR
- INTER_AREA
- INTER_CUBIC
- INTER_LANCZOS4